# Iteration in pyspark

Tags: python, for-loop, pyspark

I have a database where I have the Port, Windows, Desc and Date column, but in some cases that my key (Port and Windows) repeats, I would like to aggregate it in a single column, like this here.

I have record cases that don't repeat, I have cases that can repeat 2 times or multiple times, that's why I'd like to iterate and concatenate on a column only.

I believe it's a fortuitous intention, but I don't know how to do it.

How can I do this like pyspark?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spark, you can concatenate the `desc` and `date` column and then group by `port` and `window` and then collect_list the concatenated value and final combine them into string using `concat_ws`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [(1010, 9090, "describe pod", "01/02/22"),
        (8902, 4972, "describe pod", "22/08/21"),
        (5602, 2213, "describe pod", "23/08/21"),
        (1010, 9090, "describe pod", "01/03/22"),
        (1010, 9090, "describe faq", "02/03/22"),]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("port", "window", "desc", "date"))

combine_desc_date = F.concat(F.col("desc"), F.lit("-"), F.col("date"))
collect_new_column = F.collect_list(combine_desc_date)
new_column = F.concat_ws(" / ", collect_new_column)
df.groupBy("port", "window").agg(new_column.alias("new_column")).show(truncate=False)

"""
+----+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|port|window|new_column                                                           |
+----+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1010|9090  |describe pod-01/02/22 / describe pod-01/03/22 / describe faq-02/03/22|
|8902|4972  |describe pod-22/08/21                                                |
|5602|2213  |describe pod-23/08/21                                                |
+----+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
"""
```